# a self adjoint operator such that the matrix associated with this operator with respect to a base is not symmetrical

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find an self adjoint operator such that the matrix associated with this operator with respect to a base is not symmetrical

Comment: Try making one of the entries complex.

Comment: Try expressing the (standard) matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ in terms of a non-orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to specify whether you're talking about real or complex scalars. The complex case is too easy (see the comment above) so  I'll assume we want an operator on $\Bbb R^n$.

If $T$ is self-adjoint then the matrix representing $T$ with respect to an *orthonormal* basis is symmetric, but if the basis is not orthogonal then $T$ being self-adjoint has nothing to do with whether the matrix is symmetric. So a "random" self-adjoint $T$ with a "random" basis should give an example. Making up the first example I can think of:

Define $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$  by $$Tx=(x_2,x_1).$$(The matrix for $T$ in the standard basis is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, so $T$ is self-adjoint.)

Say $B=(b_1,b_2)$ where $b_1=(1,0)$ and $b_2=(1,1)$. Then $$Tb_1=-b_1+b_2$$and $$Tb_2=b_2,$$ so the matrix for $T$ wrt $B$ is $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.